# Regular expression with open bracket

Tags: regex, postgresql

i've been suggested to use REGEXP in postgresql to extract this column.
I would like to get the value inside the bracket which is `25.000` where the value inside this column will have 15 kinds of varieties .

```
Description
TO-CANADA/POSTCARD (Tj 25.000)/TCN-39dgr7e0e41951
```

Have tried my best to use the regexp with this query

```
select regexp_matches(description,'TO-CANADA/') from aa.bb limit 2;
```

however, the output is `{-}`

how can i extract the value inside that bracket?

Comment: The value inside the brackets is "Tj 25.000".  Why are you ignoring the first part?

Comment: yes, because i only need the value inside it, wanna do some analytics on the distributions with that value. That value represents the amount spent actually, so if i get that, then i'd plot a distribution @GordonLinoff

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this

```
# select (regexp_matches(
     'TO-CANADA/POSTCARD (Tj 25.000)/TCN-39dgr7e0e41951',
     '\(.*? ([0-9\.]+)\)' ))[1];
 regexp_matches 
---------------
 25.000
(1 row)
```